# In python what conditional statement is needed with strings/lists?

Tags: python

I am new to python and needing to write a conditional statement based on the value in list. I read in a text file with 3 columns for state, verbal score, and math score. I can find the max but I'm trying to find what states have a math score higher than 450.

I can get the math scores above 450 to print but cannot get the states to print that have math scores above 450.

```
#open the file
ACTfile = open ('state_actscores.txt', 'r')


#create blank list for the file
ACTlist = []

for line in ACTfile:
    #increment adds one to the count variable
    count += 1
    #strip the newline at the end of the line and other white space
    textline = line.strip()
    #split the line on whitespace
    items = textline.split()
    #add the list of items to the ACTlist
    ACTlist.append(items)

ACTmath = []
for line in ACTlist:
    ACTmath.append(int(line[2]))
max_math = max(ACTmath)
print(max_math)

state, verbal_score, math_score = ACTlist[0]
states = []
for (state, verbal_score, math_score) in ACTlist:
    states.append(state)
max_state = states[ACTverbal.index(max_math)]
print(max_state)

for x in ACTmath:
    if x > 450:
        print(x)
```

Comment: I read in a text file with 3 columns, state name, verbal, and math score. Line: ['Arkansas', '569', '555']
Line: ['Iowa', '593', '602']
Line: ['South_Dakota', '594', '597']
Line: ['Mississippi', '562', '547']
Line: ['North_Dakota', '582', '601']

Comment: I can get the math scores above 450 to print how can I get the state name to print if the math score is above 450?

Comment: Can you include your whole code, then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: write your input and expected output..

Comment: sorry about that. i updated to include all code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner list comprehension should give you all lists with math score above 450, assuming ACTList is populated correctly.

```
ACTlist = [['Arkansas', '569', '555'], ['Iowa', '593', '602'] ,
           ['South_Dakota', '594', '597'] , ['Mississippi', '562', '547'],
           ['North_Dakota', '582', '601']]

#Print all data for score above 450
li = [ item for item in ACTlist if int(item[2]) > 450]
print(li)
#[['Arkansas', '569', '555'], ['Iowa', '593', '602'], ['South_Dakota', '594', '597'], ['Mississippi', '562', '547'], ['North_Dakota', '582', '601']]

#Print just the states above 450
li = [ item[0] for item in ACTlist if int(item[2]) > 450]
print(li)
#['Arkansas', 'Iowa', 'South_Dakota', 'Mississippi', 'North_Dakota']
```

Then use `max` to get the maximum list from the list we got above.

```
max_score = max(li, key=lambda line: int(line[2]))
print(max_score)
#['Iowa', '593', '602']
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Is there a way to only print the list of states and not the entire string?

Comment: You mean in the first print statement?

Comment: Yes in the first print statement with finding states with a math score higher than 450

Comment: Sure updated the answer! Check if it helps you @SLG333

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much none of this mess is necessary: `max` can take a "key function", and will return the element with the maximum key function. So you can just do `max(ACTlist, key=lambda line: int(line[2]))`. This will return the maximum ACT (a triplet of state, verbal and math) by math score.

Similarly for the filtering, use a comprehension or re-convert: `[act for act in actlist if int(act[2]) > 450]` will be a list of all ACTs with a math score above 450.

Comment: Just a suggestion, it would be helpful to the OP if you include the code, input and output with the explanation you provided!